# Laravel 5.5: How to get sender email using user ID and replace id's to email in collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I now create function for get all current user messages from messages table. And in general can I change current array value using another function. For example here I must get sended date in needed format. Also get email from users table using sender id.

#### Current function code

```
public function user_messages()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $messages = Message::where('to', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($messages as $message) 
    {
        echo $message->subject; // Example Subject
        echo $message->message; // Long message text
        echo $message->from;    // Sender id. For example: 2
        echo $message->created_at; // Sended date
    }
    //return $messages;
}
```

And can I call this function on another Controller which return needed view?

### Updates question

Now I write another my function to get email. This method good or not?

```
public function getEmail($id)
{
    return User::where('id', $id)->first()->email;
}

foreach ($messages as $message) 
{
    echo $this->getEmail($message->from)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

You can use eloquent relationship in messages Model add sender and receiver function

```
public function sender() {
 return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from');
}

public function receiver() {
 return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to');
}
```

and format the date as you wish with mutation:

```
public function getCreatedAT($value) {
  return $this->attributes['created_at']->toIso8601String();
}
```

Then you can access the $message->sender and $message->receiver to get there email;

Comment: Where I must write getCreatedAT() function and how use and echo date?

Comment: In Model Message or where?

Comment: yeah you can write it in the model

Comment: I writed function getCreatedAT($value) but it not work or I can't us it. How use this method? Please show example

Comment: you can always use this instead if you still having that issue 
    protected $dateFormat = 'U';
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question than I think best way for you it's using scope, and relations:

**Message model:**

```
/** 
 * Sender relation 
 *
 * @return User 
 */
public function sender() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from');
}

/** 
 * Receiver relation 
 *
 * @return User 
 */
public function receiver() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to');
}

/** 
 * scope that return only messages which send specific user 
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeSentToUser($query, $user_id == null) 
{ 
    if (!$user_id && !\Auth::check()) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('User ID is undefined');
    } else {
        $user_id = \Auth::id();
    }
    return $query->whereHas('receiver', function($sql) use ($user_id) {
        $sql->where('id', $user_id);
    });
}
```

**Any Controller:**

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $messages Messages which were sent to auth user **/
$messages = Message::sentToUser()->get();

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection $messages Messages which were sent to user 2 **/
$anotherUserMessages = Message::sentToUser(2)->get();

foreach ($messages as $message) 
{
    echo $message->subject; // Example Subject
    echo $message->message; // Long message text
    echo $message->from;    // Sender id. For example: 2
    echo $message->created_at; // Sent date
    var_dump($message->sender); // Sender user model
    var_dump($message->receiver); // Receiver user model
}
```